# How can we import db in magento2 cloud project

Tags: database, magento2-cloud

I want to import SQL file in cloud project magento2.

by ssh i login and import db then i am getting mysql server gone away after little time later.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow:

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/setup/first-time-setup-import-import.html

And,

For PHP:
And increase default_socket_timeout in your php.ini

For MariaDB ( so probably you have to change this one only)

```
SELECT @@wait_timeout;

SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=600;

SELECT @@max_allowed_packet;

SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=107374182
```

Then restart the server and try importing again.  Maybe check first this values to get back after import.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSH tunneling to connect to a service from your local development environment as if the service were local.
Using magento-cloud cli

Step 1: Use a terminal application to log in and issue commands.

```
magento-cloud login
```

Step 2: Set up the SSH tunnel

```
magento-cloud tunnel:open -p <PROJECT_ID> -e <ENVIRONMENT_ID>
```

The response will include database connection like this

```
SSH tunnel opened to database at: mysql://username:password@127.0.0.1:PORT/database_name?compression=1
```

Use that credential to connect to the env's database on your local and do the things you want

Read more [here](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/develop/secure-connections.html?lang=en#ssh-tunneling)

Answer (score -1):

1. **Upload the .sql database file on the cloud**
2. **Crate empty database on mysql**
3. **Open ssh**
4. **Run command**

> **sudo mysql -u <DB_username> -p <databse_name> <
> /databse_file_path/databse_file.sql**